# how to calculate the time of stored data's in databse and display it in browser?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an application using codeigniter. In my application I want to calculate the time period of the contents stored in database. for example facebook displays the uploaded time in browser. is there any way to do this using codeigniter?

Comment: You mean like storing the timestamp (at the time of input) and later displaying the elapsed time since that point?

Comment: yes orourkek. is there any way to do it using codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use codeigniter but I think you can do this, in your database you create a date/hour field and in your script you simply use your system date to know the difference in hours, days or whatever you want to use to display.

something like this :

```
function (diference) {
    //all your sql traitement
    $time_elapsed = $system_date - $your_sql_result
    echo $time_elapsed;
}
```

And you can even do this with an SQL line too.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got direct access to the database in question, add a TIMESTAMP column to the table which contains the data you'd like to associate with a time. Use the 'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' during table creation to have the new column store the time the data was initially inserted, and use the 'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' during table creation to have the column's timestamp automatically updated when the data gets modified. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)